# Which JSObject should I be using?

Tags: java, javascript, applet, jsobject

I'm trying to make a Java applet interact through javascript in its enclosing environment.

Up until now, I've been using `netscape.javascript.JSObject` as the type to deal with calls to Java functions from JS, but I've just discovered that there's also a `sun.plugin.javascript.JSObject`, and even a `sun.plugin.javascript.navig.JSObject` !

I've tried finding out more about these two other versions to no avail. Should I just stick to `netscape.javascript.JSObject`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried finding out more about these two other versions to no avail. Should I just stick to `netscape.javascript.JSObject`?

Yes.  It is the public interface to other classes that might support it behind the scenes.